# Modify Loki Retention Period in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, retention, grafana-loki

I have my storage configured to use local filesystem in my Loki instance. I'm using Helm charts to install the loki-stack and I've created a yaml file to override some default values (i want to modify the default 28-days retention plan loki has to a 3-months retention plan):

(contents of my values.yaml files)

```
loki:
  chunk_store_config:
    max_look_back_period: 740h
  compactor:
    shared_store: filesystem
    working_directory: /data/loki/boltdb-shipper-compactor
    retention_enabled: true
  limits_config:
    retention_period: 740h
  schema_config:
    configs:
    - from: "2020-10-24"
    index:
      period: 24h
      prefix: index_
    object_store: filesystem
    schema: v11
    store: boltdb-shipper
  storage_config:
    boltdb_shipper:
      active_index_directory: /data/loki/boltdb-shipper-active
      cache_location: /data/loki/boltdb-shipper-cache
      cache_ttl: 24h
      shared_store: filesystem
    filesystem:
      directory: /data/loki/chunks
  table_manager:
    retention_deletes_enabled: true
    retention_period: 740h
```

i'm using the following command:

```
helm install -f values.yaml loki-stack grafana/loki-stack --set loki.enabled=true,promtail.enabled=false --namespace=my-test-ns
```

when i run the command the stack install properly and it runs just fine in my cluster however the data i configured in the yaml file is NOT applied !!
I tried a thousand different combinations to try to get this to work but it's not working. After each attempt i launch a shell in my pod and check the config under /etc/loki/loki.yaml and I only see the default configurations set for the loki instance.

Could someone please clarify how to properly modify retention periods on Loki because the method I used is what was described on the official Grafana page but it's not working (with helm and a cluster environment at least) !!

Answer (score 1):

Try to put loki configuration to config section (see statefulset template in Helm chart).

```
loki:
  config:
    ...
    compactor:
      shared_store: filesystem
      working_directory: /data/loki/boltdb-shipper-compactor
      retention_enabled: true
    limits_config:
      retention_period: 740h
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can it be done using helm install --set command like below:

```
helm upgrade --install loki grafana/loki-stack --namespace=loki --set grafana.enabled=true,\
prometheus.enabled=true,\
prometheus.alertmanager.persistentVolume.enabled=true,\
prometheus.server.persistentVolume.enabled=false,\
loki.persistence.enabled=true,\
loki.persistence.storageClassName=gp2,\
loki.persistence.size=105Gi,\
loki.limits_config.retention_period=192h,\
config.table_manager.retention_deletes_enabled=true,\
config.table_manager.retention_period=192h,\
loki.limits_config.max_entries_limit=15000,\
compactor.retention_enabled=true,\
compactor.retention_delete_delay=2h,\
compactor.compaction_interval=10m,\
compactor.retention_delete_worker_count=150
```

Here I am using the below configuration flag:

```
loki.limits_config.retention_period=192h
```